# How to manipulate checkboxes with lxml

Tags: forms, python-3.x, lxml

I've followed the lxml documentation [here](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) and still cannot get it to check the checkbox. I'm pretty new to python and lxml but this seems like a pretty simple task.

I don't get any errors with the below code and I've confirmed that the input name is correct by running:

```
print(page.forms[1].inputs.keys())
```

I've tried using following variations to get the code to work, all to no avail:

```
page.forms[1].inputs['LH_TitleDesc'].value = "1"
page.forms[1].inputs['LH_TitleDesc'].value = "0"
page.forms[1].inputs['LH_TitleDesc'].checked = True
page.forms[1].inputs['LH_TitleDesc'].checked = "TRUE"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `...checked = True`. Python's boolean values are called `True` and `False`.

Comment: I tried, no dice...updated question to reflect attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I just tinkered around with it more by using firebug and noticed the only that by default the checkbox is unchecked and that the value was set to 1. Therefore this is the code that fixed the issue (notice lack of quotations!

```
page.forms[1].inputs['LH_TitleDesc'].value = 0
```